# how to write a function which calls a simulink file in it

Tags: function, 2d, simulink, matlab

i just wrote a m-file with some defined input in which a simulink file is called.

it worked correctly
but when I'm going to define a function based on the same m-file ( so i can give multiple inputs to it) it give's me this error :

""
Invalid matrix-format variable specified as workspace input in 'blocks/From Workspace'. The matrix
must have two dimensions and at least two columns. Complex signals of any data type and non-double
real signals must be in structure format. The first column must contain time values and the
remaining columns the data values.
""

but i'm pretty sure that variable has 2 dimension and has twoo coloumns.

i don't have any idea what to do here.

what can i do here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying the mfile that runs your Simulink simulation works when the mfile is a script, but not when the mfile is a function? If so, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279199/how-do-i-provide-input-to-a-simulink-model-without-placing-it-in-the-workspace) may provide some insight. Despite a preference for functions, I use scripts to run Simulink parameter studies - it was just easier to set up.

Comment: thank you for your help ,, this code worked:

 options = simset('SrcWorkspace','current');
  sim('modelname',[],options)

Comment: @MohamadPishdad, upvote all answers that are helpful, and accept the answer which resolves your issue.