# Retain interactivity in Simulink sheet called from an object method

Tags: matlab, simulink, matlab-class

Let's say I have a simulation set up in Simulink, which consists of three blocks: Input (`From Workspace` block), model calculation (`S-function` block) and results (`Outport`).
In my class, I do a lot of preprocessing on the input data, which is not shown here. Then, I point the Input block to use the `inputArray`, which is a property of my class.

```
classdef SimulationClass < handle
    %SimulationClass Simulate process using model 
    properties
        inputArray double = ones(101, 11)
        modelFilename char
        simOpts struct
        simulationTime double
        simulationResultsArray double
    end

    methods
        function obj = SimulationClass(simulationTime)
            obj.simulationTime = simulationTime;
        end

        function prepareSimulation(obj, modelFilename)
            obj.modelFilename = modelFilename;
            open_system(obj.modelFilename);
            set_param([obj.modelFilename '/fromWorkspaceBlock'],...
                'VariableName', 'obj.inputArray');
            obj.simOpts = simset('SrcWorkspace', 'current');
        end

        function runSimulation(obj)
            [~, ~, obj.simulationResultsArray] = sim(obj.modelFilename,...
                obj.simulationTime, obj.simOpts);
        end
    end
end
```

I can easily start the simulation run from the command prompt.

```
mySim = SimulationClass(1:10);
mySim.prepareSimulation('mySimulinkSheet');
mySim.runSimulation;
```

But, if I play around with some settings (e.g., different solvers) and press *Run* in Simulink, it doesn't work, since the data is not in the `base` workspace. I.e., I lose the interactivity with Simulink.

Any ideas on how to resolve this issue? The only [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279199/how-do-i-provide-input-to-a-simulink-model-without-placing-it-in-the-workspace) I have figured out so far would be to write an additional method (like `writePropertiesToBaseWorkspace`) which would convert the classes `properties` into variables, using `assignin()`.

Comment: How else do you expect the workspace variables to exist without creating them in some script or otherwise? I'm not sure how this is very different from the question you linked...

Comment: Well, it would be easier to have Simulink use the object's workspace even in interactive mode. But as soon as I hit the *Run* button, it starts looking for the variables only in the base workspace... Or maybe there's a different kind of block I could use for the `input` part, instead of `From Workspace`!?

Comment: You would need to use the workaround you mentioned to write your data to base workspace. When running interactively you do not have your  workspace in class methods available to Simulink.